# Django - serialize to JSON, how to serialize a FK User object

Tags: django, json, serialization, foreign-keys

I'm on a page which sends a request to server side for a list of comments of current topic.

like this

localhost:8000/getComments/567  , while 567 is the topic id.

then, in my django view, like this:

```
def getProjectComments(request, pId):
    format = 'json'
    mimetype = 'application/javascript'  #'application/xml' for 'xml' format
    comments = PrjComment.objects.filter(prj=pId)
    data = serializers.serialize(format, comments)
    return HttpResponse(data,mimetype)
```

Now , the question is ,
when I try to use jQuery.parseJSON(data) at the browser side.

```
[
 {
   "pk": 10, 
    "model": "app.prjcomment", 
    "fields": 
     {
      "status": 1, 
      "time_Commented": "2011-12-11 17:23:56", 
      "prj": 1, 
      "content": "my comment 1", 
      "user": 25
     }
  }, 
  {
   "pk": 9, 
   "model": "app.prjcomment", 
   "fields": {
     "status": 1, 
     "time_Commented": "2011-12-11 17:23:51", 
     "prj": 1, 
     "content": "comment \u4e00\u4e2a", 
     "user": 33
   }
 } ..
```

I need to use some detail information of user object.  (user is a Foreign Key in model PrjComment)
such as user.first_name  to display on the comment list.

but here it is only an id for user.("user": 33)
How can I do that?  Anyone who can kind help?
Thank you very much

the User is the Django auth_user.

Comment: Finally , i used the raw sql to implement this feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easy solution would be to specify the values you need:

```
comments = PrjComment.objects.filter(prj=pId) \
                     .values('status','time_commented','prj','content','user__id',
                             'user__username','user__first_name')
```

**Update:**

To access your userprofile information use the table name as defined in your AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE setting. In my case the table is called userprofile, and I'd access the data like this:

```
values('user__userprofile__moreinfo')
```

where moreinfo is the field you're interested in

Comment: thank you very much , it works for me, but here comes another question. I can't access 'user.get_profile'  in the filter().values(). The user__first_name can get the first_name , but I can't get the user properties in the userprofile table.  I tried user__get_profile, this doesn't work for me. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: the userprofile still not work for me   in settings.xml  AUTH_PROFILE_MODULE = 'hedan.UserProfile'====>FieldError at /projects/morecomments/1/11
Cannot resolve keyword 'user__UserProfile__telephone' into field. Choices are: cId, content, prj, replys, status